# how to test functions within a functional component REACT using jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am struggling to test functions with a pure functional component in react using jest. I was hoping to use jest.spyon but that is only available with class based REACT components

Comment: I am trying to figure something similar as well. I haven't come across an example post as yet.